# Memory leak in cuda program

Tags: c, memory-leaks, cuda

I've written a CUDA program for simulating [John Conway's Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life), but sometimes I get a memory leak (cells appear that shouldn't be there).

here is my kernel:

```
__global__ void gameOfLife(matrix pcuda_main,int lblock,int generations_to_run) {
/************************************
notice: first dimension is one section for read and one for 
write(change purpose every simulation generation). 2 extra section rows
for first and last line not need to check their up and down position evry time
also edge lines ensure that blocks handles edge sectors are having edge lines less that other blocks
************************************/
    __shared__ unsigned int section[2][SECTION_SIZE][CELLS_IN_LINE];
    int i,j;
    unsigned int sum_top_b1,sum_top_b0,sum_cur_b1,sum_cur_b0,sum_bot_b1,sum_bot_b0,newone,newtwo,new4a,new4b;
    unsigned int left_top,left,left_bot,right_top,right,right_bot;
    int read_section=0;
    int write_section=1;
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int row = SECTION_ROWS*blockIdx.x+threadIdx.x;
    int rowx = threadIdx.x+SECTION_ROWS;

    // I am zeroeing the perimiters lines since they dont loaded with values and can be corrupt while more lines may be zeroes its done for avoiding ifs
    section[0][rowx>>LINE_NUMBER_BITS_OFFSET][rowx&CELLS_IN_LINE_RESIDUE] = 0;
    section[1][rowx>>LINE_NUMBER_BITS_OFFSET][rowx&CELLS_IN_LINE_RESIDUE] = 0;
    section[0][SECTION_ROWS-1-(rowx>>LINE_NUMBER_BITS_OFFSET)][rowx&CELLS_IN_LINE_RESIDUE] = 0;
    section[1][SECTION_ROWS-1-(rowx>>LINE_NUMBER_BITS_OFFSET)][rowx&CELLS_IN_LINE_RESIDUE] = 0;
    section[0][3*SECTION_ROWS+1-(rowx>>LINE_NUMBER_BITS_OFFSET)][rowx&CELLS_IN_LINE_RESIDUE] = 0;
    section[1][3*SECTION_ROWS+1-(rowx>>LINE_NUMBER_BITS_OFFSET)][rowx&CELLS_IN_LINE_RESIDUE] = 0;
    section[0][2*SECTION_ROWS+1-(rowx>>LINE_NUMBER_BITS_OFFSET)][rowx&CELLS_IN_LINE_RESIDUE] = 0;
    section[1][2*SECTION_ROWS+1-(rowx>>LINE_NUMBER_BITS_OFFSET)][rowx&CELLS_IN_LINE_RESIDUE] = 0;
    __syncthreads(); // ensure no crashes between zeroeing perimiter lines and loading data
    // since entire warp access the first and last cell together no extrag edges are needed however only first and last line access lines beyond the edges
    for(i=0;i<CELLS_IN_LINE;i++) {
        if ( bx > 0 ) {
            section[0][rowx-SECTION_ROWS+1][i] = pcuda_main[((row-SECTION_ROWS)<<LINE_NUMBER_BITS_OFFSET)+i];
        }
        section[0][rowx+1][i] = pcuda_main[((row)<<LINE_NUMBER_BITS_OFFSET)+i];
        if ( bx < lblock ) {
            // not last block sector row
            section[0][rowx+SECTION_ROWS+1][i] = pcuda_main[((row+SECTION_ROWS)<<LINE_NUMBER_BITS_OFFSET)+i];
        }
    }
    __syncthreads(); // ensure all data read
    for ( i=0;i<generations_to_run;i++ ) {
        for(j=0;j<CELLS_IN_LINE;j++) {
            if ( bx > 0 ) {
                if ( j > 0 ) {
                    left_top = section[read_section][rowx-SECTION_ROWS][j-1];
                    left = section[read_section][rowx-SECTION_ROWS+1][j-1];
                    left_bot = section[read_section][rowx-SECTION_ROWS+2][j-1];
                } else {
                    left_top = 0;
                    left=0;
                    left_bot=0;
                }
                if ( j<CELLS_IN_LINE_RESIDUE ) {
                    right_top= section[read_section][rowx-SECTION_ROWS][j+1];
                    right= section[read_section][rowx-SECTION_ROWS+1][j+1];
                    right_bot= section[read_section][rowx-SECTION_ROWS+2][j+1];
                } else {
                    right_top = 0;
                    right=0;
                    right_bot=0;
                }

                CELL32(section[write_section][rowx-SECTION_ROWS+1][j],
                    left_top,section[read_section][rowx-SECTION_ROWS][j],right_top,
                    left,section[read_section][rowx-SECTION_ROWS+1][j],right,
                    left_bot,section[read_section][rowx-SECTION_ROWS+2][j],right_bot,
                    sum_top_b1,sum_top_b0,sum_cur_b1,sum_cur_b0,sum_bot_b1,sum_bot_b0,newone,newtwo,new4a,new4b);
            }
            if ( j > 0 ) {
                left_top = section[read_section][rowx][j-1];
                left = section[read_section][rowx+1][j-1];
                left_bot = section[read_section][rowx+2][j-1];
            } else {
                left_top = 0;
                left=0;
                left_bot=0;
            }
            if ( j<CELLS_IN_LINE_RESIDUE ) {
                right_top= section[read_section][rowx][j+1];
                right= section[read_section][rowx+1][j+1];
                right_bot= section[read_section][rowx+2][j+1];
            } else {
                right_top = 0;
                right=0;
                right_bot=0;
            }
            CELL32(section[write_section][rowx+1][j],
                left_top,section[read_section][rowx][j],right_top,
                left,section[read_section][rowx+1][j],right,
                left_bot,section[read_section][rowx+2][j],right_bot,
                sum_top_b1,sum_top_b0,sum_cur_b1,sum_cur_b0,sum_bot_b1,sum_bot_b0,newone,newtwo,new4a,new4b);
            if ( bx < lblock ) {
                if ( j > 0 ) {
                    left_top = section[read_section][rowx+SECTION_ROWS][j-1];
                    left = section[read_section][rowx+SECTION_ROWS+1][j-1];
                    left_bot = section[read_section][rowx+SECTION_ROWS+2][j-1];
                } else {
                    left_top = 0;
                    left=0;
                    left_bot=0;
                }
                if ( j<CELLS_IN_LINE_RESIDUE ) {
                    right_top= section[read_section][rowx+SECTION_ROWS][j+1];
                    right= section[read_section][rowx+SECTION_ROWS+1][j+1];
                    right_bot= section[read_section][rowx+SECTION_ROWS+2][j+1];
                } else {
                    right_top = 0;
                    right=0;
                    right_bot=0;
                }
                CELL32(section[write_section][rowx+SECTION_ROWS+1][j],
                    left_top,section[read_section][rowx+SECTION_ROWS][j],right_top,
                    left,section[read_section][rowx+SECTION_ROWS+1][j],right,
                    left_bot,section[read_section][rowx+SECTION_ROWS+2][j],right_bot,
                    sum_top_b1,sum_top_b0,sum_cur_b1,sum_cur_b0,sum_bot_b1,sum_bot_b0,newone,newtwo,new4a,new4b);
            }
        }
        read_section = read_section^1;
        write_section = write_section^1;
        //printf("passed %u generation for row: %u\n",i,row);
        __syncthreads();
    }

    // now writing back to the global memory notice write section turns into read section after every generation so 
    // I write the read section
    for(i=0;i<CELLS_IN_LINE;i++) {
        pcuda_main[((row)<<LINE_NUMBER_BITS_OFFSET)+i] = section[read_section][rowx+1][i];
    }
    __syncthreads();
}
```

here is the cell 32 definition and its dependents:

```
#define HALFADDER(s0,s1,a0,a1)do{s1=(a0)&(a1);s0=(a0)^(a1);}while(0)
#define FULLADDER(s0,s1,a0,a1,a2)do{s1=((a0)&(a1))|((a2)&((a0)^(a1)));s0 =(a2)^((a0)^(a1));}while(0)

#define CELL32(output,top_left,top,top_right,left,cur,right,bot_left,bot,bot_right,sum_top_b1,sum_top_b0,sum_cur_b1,sum_cur_b0,sum_bot_b1,sum_bot_b0,newone,newtwo,new4a,new4b)do{FULLADDER(sum_top_b0,sum_top_b1,(top_left<<31)|(top>>1),top,(top_right>>31)|(top<<1));HALFADDER(sum_cur_b0,sum_cur_b1,(left<<31)|(cur>>1),(right>>31)|(cur<<1));FULLADDER(sum_bot_b0,sum_bot_b1,(bot_left<<31)|(bot>>1),bot,((bot_right>>31)|(bot<<1)));FULLADDER(newone,newtwo,sum_bot_b0,sum_cur_b0,sum_top_b0);FULLADDER(newtwo,new4a,newtwo,sum_bot_b1,sum_top_b1);HALFADDER(newtwo,new4b,newtwo,sum_cur_b1);newone=newone|cur;output=newone&newtwo&(~new4a)&(~new4b);}while(0)
```

and here is the primary loop and memory copies:

```
cudaMalloc((void **)(&pcuda),NUM_CELLS*sizeof(unsigned int));
    //cudaMalloc((void **)(&pdata),ROWS*sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy((void *)pcuda,(void *)p,sizeof(unsigned int)*NUM_CELLS,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    while ( generations > 0 ) {
        if ( generations > SECTION_ROWS ) {
            generations_run = SECTION_ROWS;
        } else {
            generations_run = generations;
        }
        generations -= generations_run;
        printf("running params last_row:%u, generations_run:%u, generations left:%u,grid size:%d, array size in bytes: %u,last cell index: %d\n",
            ROWS-SECTION_ROWS,generations_run,generations,dimGrid.x,NUM_CELLS*sizeof(unsigned int),((ROWS-1)<<LINE_NUMBER_BITS_OFFSET)+CELLS_IN_LINE_RESIDUE);
        gameOfLife<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(pcuda,dimGrid.x-1,generations_run);
        error = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        if (error != cudaSuccess)
        {
            printf("cudaGetDeviceProperties returned error code %d, line(%d)\n", error, __LINE__);
            lineid = __LINE__;
            err = error;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("GPU Device %d:synchronized\n", devID);
        }
    }
    cudaMemcpy((void *)p,(void *)pcuda,sizeof(int)*NUM_CELLS,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

where is the memory leaked?

Comment: CUDA includes a tool called `cuda-memcheck` for diagnosing memory leaks and usage problems. I suggest you familiarise yourself with it.

Comment: You could use cuda-memcheck to help locate the mem leaking

Answer (score 4):

The CUDA toolkit comes with cuda-memcheck which will, by default, check for out-of-bounds access within a kernel. It also has other modes, including a leak checker. Note that you'll need to call cudaDeviceReset() before exiting so that the tool knows to look for unreleased device memory.

Comment: the problem here is that I probably read from outbound my array since its some times finish with only few cell corrupted at the end of the array, but the most error I get is mis aligned cell and not always, which not make sense I have unsigned int array and I read their cells

Comment: Like I said, it checks for OOB accesses.